# Fit wide table to landscape page - Legibility

Tags: tables, pdflscape, lscape

I have a wide table to fit in a landscape page. I'm trying a combination of

1. changing the font size of the header paragraph
2. changing the font size of the table contents
3. resizing the table in a `resizebox`
4. setting the width of the `tabular` environment

Is there a better way to do this? What's the best way to fit a table such as this to a page? To date, I've just been using trial and error with `\resizebox{1.0\linewidth}{!}{` and `\begin{tabular*}{1.6\linewidth}{@{`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{My Caption}
\label{table:ufukFour}
\footnotesize                                   %Option (a) 
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{center}
\scriptsize                                     %Option (b) 
\resizebox{1.0\linewidth}{!}{                   %Option (c) 
\begin{tabular*}{1.6\linewidth}{@{              %Option (d) 
\global\let\restorecr=\\ 
\extracolsep{\fill} } cc rrrrr rrrrr rrrrr}
\toprule        
%\global\let\oldcr=\\ 
%\global\def\crsng{\global\let\\ =\crtri\oldcr}
%\global\def\crdbl{\global\let\\ =\crsng\oldcr}
%\global\def\crtri{\global\let\\ =\crdbl\oldcr[10pt]}
%\global\let\\=\crtri

\global\let\oldcr=\\ 
\global\def\crsng{\global\let\\ =\crqua\oldcr}
\global\def\crdbl{\global\let\\ =\crsng\oldcr}
\global\def\crtri{\global\let\\ =\crdbl\oldcr}
\global\def\crqua{\global\let\\ =\crtri\oldcr[10pt]}
\global\let\\=\crqua

&&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{One}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Two}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Three}} \vspace{-0.3cm}\\

\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}

&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 5} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Cat 5} \tabularnewline

\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}
&&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: First Panel}}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}
    ~First    & A     &       47\%     &       34\%     &       21\%     &       21\%     &       18\%     &       40\%     &       31\%     &       25\%     &       19\%     &       18\%     &       26\%     &       24\%     &       19\%     &       14\%     &       12\%    \\
   ~ & B     &       29\%     &       38\%     &       49\%     &       50\%     &       52\%     &       43\%     &       48\%     &       51\%     &       55\%     &       56\%     &       63\%     &       61\%     &       64\%     &       68\%     &       67\%    \\
   ~ & C    &       24\%     &       28\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       17\%     &       21\%     &       24\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       10\%     &       15\%     &       17\%     &       18\%     &       21\%    \\
   ~ & N    & \textit{11494}    &  \textit{4089}    &  \textit{3239}    &  \textit{1904}    &  \textit{1322}    &  \textit{4801}    &  \textit{2471}    &  \textit{1795}    &  \textit{1438}    &  \textit{1187}    &   \textit{808}    &   \textit{651}    &   \textit{557}    &   \textit{529}    &   \textit{459}   \\
Second    & A     &       25\%     &       18\%     &       14\%     &       11\%     &       10\%     &       18\%     &       13\%     &        9\%     &        8\%     &        8\%     &       14\%     &        8\%     &        6\%     &        5\%     &        4\%    \\
   ~ & B     &       55\%     &       59\%     &       63\%     &       64\%     &       64\%     &       65\%     &       68\%     &       72\%     &       73\%     &       73\%     &       76\%     &       81\%     &       83\%     &       84\%     &       85\%    \\
   ~ & C    &       20\%     &       23\%     &       23\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       17\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       20\%     &        9\%     &       11\%     &       11\%     &       12\%     &       11\%    \\
   ~ & N    &  \textit{7801}    &  \textit{6363}    &  \textit{4018}    &  \textit{3166}    &  \textit{2643}    &  \textit{6279}    &  \textit{6151}    &  \textit{5336}    &  \textit{5208}    &  \textit{4861}    &  \textit{1707}    &  \textit{2268}    &  \textit{2615}    &  \textit{2905}    &  \textit{3053}   \\

\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}
%
&&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: Second Panel}} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}
    ~First    & A     &       47\%     &       34\%     &       21\%     &       21\%     &       18\%     &       40\%     &       31\%     &       25\%     &       19\%     &       18\%     &       26\%     &       24\%     &       19\%     &       14\%     &       12\%    \\
   ~ & B     &       29\%     &       38\%     &       49\%     &       50\%     &       52\%     &       43\%     &       48\%     &       51\%     &       55\%     &       56\%     &       63\%     &       61\%     &       64\%     &       68\%     &       67\%    \\
   ~ & C    &       24\%     &       28\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       17\%     &       21\%     &       24\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       10\%     &       15\%     &       17\%     &       18\%     &       21\%    \\
   ~ & N    & \textit{11494}    &  \textit{4089}    &  \textit{3239}    &  \textit{1904}    &  \textit{1322}    &  \textit{4801}    &  \textit{2471}    &  \textit{1795}    &  \textit{1438}    &  \textit{1187}    &   \textit{808}    &   \textit{651}    &   \textit{557}    &   \textit{529}    &   \textit{459}   \\
Second    & A     &       25\%     &       18\%     &       14\%     &       11\%     &       10\%     &       18\%     &       13\%     &        9\%     &        8\%     &        8\%     &       14\%     &        8\%     &        6\%     &        5\%     &        4\%    \\
   ~ & B     &       55\%     &       59\%     &       63\%     &       64\%     &       64\%     &       65\%     &       68\%     &       72\%     &       73\%     &       73\%     &       76\%     &       81\%     &       83\%     &       84\%     &       85\%    \\
   ~ & C    &       20\%     &       23\%     &       23\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       17\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       20\%     &        9\%     &       11\%     &       11\%     &       12\%     &       11\%    \\
   ~ & N    &  \textit{7801}    &  \textit{6363}    &  \textit{4018}    &  \textit{3166}    &  \textit{2643}    &  \textit{6279}    &  \textit{6151}    &  \textit{5336}    &  \textit{5208}    &  \textit{4861}    &  \textit{1707}    &  \textit{2268}    &  \textit{2615}    &  \textit{2905}    &  \textit{3053}   \\       
    \cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}
%
&&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel C: Third Panel}} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule(lr){3-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-12}
\cmidrule(lr){13-17}
    ~First    & A     &       47\%     &       34\%     &       21\%     &       21\%     &       18\%     &       40\%     &       31\%     &       25\%     &       19\%     &       18\%     &       26\%     &       24\%     &       19\%     &       14\%     &       12\%    \\
   ~ & B     &       29\%     &       38\%     &       49\%     &       50\%     &       52\%     &       43\%     &       48\%     &       51\%     &       55\%     &       56\%     &       63\%     &       61\%     &       64\%     &       68\%     &       67\%    \\
   ~ & C    &       24\%     &       28\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       17\%     &       21\%     &       24\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       10\%     &       15\%     &       17\%     &       18\%     &       21\%    \\
   ~ & N    & \textit{11494}    &  \textit{4089}    &  \textit{3239}    &  \textit{1904}    &  \textit{1322}    &  \textit{4801}    &  \textit{2471}    &  \textit{1795}    &  \textit{1438}    &  \textit{1187}    &   \textit{808}    &   \textit{651}    &   \textit{557}    &   \textit{529}    &   \textit{459}   \\
Second    & A     &       25\%     &       18\%     &       14\%     &       11\%     &       10\%     &       18\%     &       13\%     &        9\%     &        8\%     &        8\%     &       14\%     &        8\%     &        6\%     &        5\%     &        4\%    \\
   ~ & B     &       55\%     &       59\%     &       63\%     &       64\%     &       64\%     &       65\%     &       68\%     &       72\%     &       73\%     &       73\%     &       76\%     &       81\%     &       83\%     &       84\%     &       85\%    \\
   ~ & C    &       20\%     &       23\%     &       23\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       17\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       20\%     &        9\%     &       11\%     &       11\%     &       12\%     &       11\%    \\
   ~ & N    &  \textit{7801}    &  \textit{6363}    &  \textit{4018}    &  \textit{3166}    &  \textit{2643}    &  \textit{6279}    &  \textit{6151}    &  \textit{5336}    &  \textit{5208}    &  \textit{4861}    &  \textit{1707}    &  \textit{2268}    &  \textit{2615}    &  \textit{2905}    &  \textit{3053}   \\       
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your table does fit the page horizontally. What else do you need? For vertical correction you will have to get rid of rows, text or fontsize. Please reduce your problem to a minimum. If you want to see borders of your landscape document, use `\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}` with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The horizontal fit is fine. What I'm asking is how to use a more systematic way of fitting tables as opposed to trial and error with `resizebox`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a "normal" paper size (i.e., A4 or US-Letter) and 1" margins, the table will fit in landscape mode if you use `\footnotesize` and set the default amount of intercolumn whitespace to a very small value; by using a `tabular*` environment and the `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive, you can tell LaTeX to perform the chore of making the table fit exactly in the width of the text block. (A nice side-effect of this setup, by the way, is that you needn't provide any trimming options to the `\cmidrule` directives.)

In order to create a bit more of an "open" look, do insert a few `\addlinespace` instructions here and there.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,eurosym,caption}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shorcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\caption{My Caption}
\label{table:Four}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1mm} % let LaTeX calculate intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
      c *{15}{r} }
\toprule        

&&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{One}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Two}}
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Three}} \\

\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}

&&\mc{Cat 1} & \mc{Cat 2} & \mc{Cat 3} & \mc{Cat 4} & \mc{Cat 5} 
& \mc{Cat 1} & \mc{Cat 2} & \mc{Cat 3} & \mc{Cat 4} & \mc{Cat 5} 
& \mc{Cat 1} & \mc{Cat 2} & \mc{Cat 3} & \mc{Cat 4} & \mc{Cat 5} \\

\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
\addlinespace

&&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: First Panel}}\\
\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
    First    & A     &       47\%     &       34\%     &       21\%     &       21\%     &       18\%     &       40\%     &       31\%     &       25\%     &       19\%     &       18\%     &       26\%     &       24\%     &       19\%     &       14\%     &       12\%    \\
    & B     &       29\%     &       38\%     &       49\%     &       50\%     &       52\%     &       43\%     &       48\%     &       51\%     &       55\%     &       56\%     &       63\%     &       61\%     &       64\%     &       68\%     &       67\%    \\
    & C    &       24\%     &       28\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       17\%     &       21\%     &       24\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       10\%     &       15\%     &       17\%     &       18\%     &       21\%    \\
    & N    & \textit{11494}    &  \textit{4089}    &  \textit{3239}    &  \textit{1904}    &  \textit{1322}    &  \textit{4801}    &  \textit{2471}    &  \textit{1795}    &  \textit{1438}    &  \textit{1187}    &   \textit{808}    &   \textit{651}    &   \textit{557}    &   \textit{529}    &   \textit{459}   \\
\addlinespace
Second    & A     &       25\%     &       18\%     &       14\%     &       11\%     &       10\%     &       18\%     &       13\%     &        9\%     &        8\%     &        8\%     &       14\%     &        8\%     &        6\%     &        5\%     &        4\%    \\
    & B     &       55\%     &       59\%     &       63\%     &       64\%     &       64\%     &       65\%     &       68\%     &       72\%     &       73\%     &       73\%     &       76\%     &       81\%     &       83\%     &       84\%     &       85\%    \\
    & C    &       20\%     &       23\%     &       23\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       17\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       20\%     &        9\%     &       11\%     &       11\%     &       12\%     &       11\%    \\
    & N    &  \textit{7801}    &  \textit{6363}    &  \textit{4018}    &  \textit{3166}    &  \textit{2643}    &  \textit{6279}    &  \textit{6151}    &  \textit{5336}    &  \textit{5208}    &  \textit{4861}    &  \textit{1707}    &  \textit{2268}    &  \textit{2615}    &  \textit{2905}    &  \textit{3053}   \\

\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
\addlinespace

&&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: Second Panel}} \\
\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
    First    & A     &       47\%     &       34\%     &       21\%     &       21\%     &       18\%     &       40\%     &       31\%     &       25\%     &       19\%     &       18\%     &       26\%     &       24\%     &       19\%     &       14\%     &       12\%    \\
    & B     &       29\%     &       38\%     &       49\%     &       50\%     &       52\%     &       43\%     &       48\%     &       51\%     &       55\%     &       56\%     &       63\%     &       61\%     &       64\%     &       68\%     &       67\%    \\
    & C    &       24\%     &       28\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       17\%     &       21\%     &       24\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       10\%     &       15\%     &       17\%     &       18\%     &       21\%    \\
    & N    & \textit{11494}    &  \textit{4089}    &  \textit{3239}    &  \textit{1904}    &  \textit{1322}    &  \textit{4801}    &  \textit{2471}    &  \textit{1795}    &  \textit{1438}    &  \textit{1187}    &   \textit{808}    &   \textit{651}    &   \textit{557}    &   \textit{529}    &   \textit{459}   \\
\addlinespace
Second    & A     &       25\%     &       18\%     &       14\%     &       11\%     &       10\%     &       18\%     &       13\%     &        9\%     &        8\%     &        8\%     &       14\%     &        8\%     &        6\%     &        5\%     &        4\%    \\
    & B     &       55\%     &       59\%     &       63\%     &       64\%     &       64\%     &       65\%     &       68\%     &       72\%     &       73\%     &       73\%     &       76\%     &       81\%     &       83\%     &       84\%     &       85\%    \\
    & C    &       20\%     &       23\%     &       23\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       17\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       20\%     &        9\%     &       11\%     &       11\%     &       12\%     &       11\%    \\
    & N    &  \textit{7801}    &  \textit{6363}    &  \textit{4018}    &  \textit{3166}    &  \textit{2643}    &  \textit{6279}    &  \textit{6151}    &  \textit{5336}    &  \textit{5208}    &  \textit{4861}    &  \textit{1707}    &  \textit{2268}    &  \textit{2615}    &  \textit{2905}    &  \textit{3053}   \\       
\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
\addlinespace
&&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel C: Third Panel}} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
    First    & A     &       47\%     &       34\%     &       21\%     &       21\%     &       18\%     &       40\%     &       31\%     &       25\%     &       19\%     &       18\%     &       26\%     &       24\%     &       19\%     &       14\%     &       12\%    \\
    & B     &       29\%     &       38\%     &       49\%     &       50\%     &       52\%     &       43\%     &       48\%     &       51\%     &       55\%     &       56\%     &       63\%     &       61\%     &       64\%     &       68\%     &       67\%    \\
    & C    &       24\%     &       28\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       30\%     &       17\%     &       21\%     &       24\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       10\%     &       15\%     &       17\%     &       18\%     &       21\%    \\
    & N    & \textit{11494}    &  \textit{4089}    &  \textit{3239}    &  \textit{1904}    &  \textit{1322}    &  \textit{4801}    &  \textit{2471}    &  \textit{1795}    &  \textit{1438}    &  \textit{1187}    &   \textit{808}    &   \textit{651}    &   \textit{557}    &   \textit{529}    &   \textit{459}   \\
\addlinespace
Second    & A     &       25\%     &       18\%     &       14\%     &       11\%     &       10\%     &       18\%     &       13\%     &        9\%     &        8\%     &        8\%     &       14\%     &        8\%     &        6\%     &        5\%     &        4\%    \\
    & B     &       55\%     &       59\%     &       63\%     &       64\%     &       64\%     &       65\%     &       68\%     &       72\%     &       73\%     &       73\%     &       76\%     &       81\%     &       83\%     &       84\%     &       85\%    \\
    & C    &       20\%     &       23\%     &       23\%     &       26\%     &       26\%     &       17\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       19\%     &       20\%     &        9\%     &       11\%     &       11\%     &       12\%     &       11\%    \\
    & N    &  \textit{7801}    &  \textit{6363}    &  \textit{4018}    &  \textit{3166}    &  \textit{2643}    &  \textit{6279}    &  \textit{6151}    &  \textit{5336}    &  \textit{5208}    &  \textit{4861}    &  \textit{1707}    &  \textit{2268}    &  \textit{2615}    &  \textit{2905}    &  \textit{3053} 
\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fit the table to the page, you will have to use a `tabularx` and it's X-columns. However, your table is too big and you will have to get rid of some content or type it really small. I would not do that.

I reduced the width of your table for you. Please reduce your example to a minimum and ask for a specific problem. For example: "How do I set a tabular to full \textwidth?"

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\itshape

\begin{document} 
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}
            \sisetup{detect-all}
            \caption{My Caption (all values in \si{\percent})}\label{table:Four}
            \footnotesize 
            \lipsum[1]\vspace{1ex} 
            \centering\scriptsize
            \begin{tabular}{%
                    @{}rc 
                    S[table-format=5.0,group-four-digits]
                    *{4}{S[table-format=4.0]} 
                    *{5}{S[table-format=4.0]} 
                    *{5}{S[table-format=4.0]}@{}
                }\toprule 
                & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{One}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Two}} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Three}}\\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                & & {Cat 1} & {Cat 2} & {Cat 3} & {Cat 4} & {Cat 5} 
                & {Cat 1} & {Cat 2} & {Cat 3} & {Cat 4} & {Cat 5} 
                & {Cat 1} & {Cat 2} & {Cat 3} & {Cat 4} & {Cat 5} \\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                &&\multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: First Panel}} \\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                First & A & 47 & 34 & 21 & 21 & 18 & 40 & 31 & 25 & 19 & 18 & 26 & 24 & 19 & 14 & 12 \\
                & B & 29 & 38 & 49 & 50 & 52 & 43 & 48 & 51 & 55 & 56 & 63 & 61 & 64 & 68 & 67 \\
                & C & 24 & 28 & 30 & 30 & 30 & 17 & 21 & 24 & 26 & 26 & 10 & 15 & 17 & 18 & 21 \\
                & N & \itshape11494 & \itshape4089 & \itshape3239 & \itshape1904 & \itshape1322 & \itshape4801 & \itshape2471 & \itshape1795 & \itshape1438 & \itshape1187 & \itshape808 & \itshape 651 & \itshape557 & \itshape529 & \itshape459 \\\addlinespace
                Second & A & 25 & 18 & 14 & 11 & 10 & 18 & 13 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 14 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
                & B & 55 & 59 & 63 & 64 & 64 & 65 & 68 & 72 & 73 & 73 & 76 & 81 & 83 & 84 & 85 \\
                & C & 20 & 23 & 23 & 26 & 26 & 17 & 19 & 19 & 19 & 20 & 9 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 11 \\
                & N & \itshape7801 & \itshape6363 & \itshape4018 & \itshape3166 & \itshape2643 & \itshape6279 & \itshape6151 & \itshape5336 & \itshape5208 & \itshape4861 & \itshape1707 & \itshape2268 & \itshape2615 & \itshape2905 & \itshape3053 \\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                & & \multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: Second Panel}} \\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                First & A & 47 & 34 & 21 & 21 & 18 & 40 & 31 & 25 & 19 & 18 & 26 & 24 & 19 & 14 & 12 \\
                & B & 29 & 38 & 49 & 50 & 52 & 43 & 48 & 51 & 55 & 56 & 63 & 61 & 64 & 68 & 67 \\
                & C & 24 & 28 & 30 & 30 & 30 & 17 & 21 & 24 & 26 & 26 & 10 & 15 & 17 & 18 & 21 \\
                & N & \itshape11494 & \itshape4089 & \itshape3239 & \itshape1904 & \itshape1322 & \itshape4801 & \itshape2471 & \itshape1795 & \itshape1438 & \itshape1187 & \itshape808 & \itshape651 & \itshape557 & \itshape529 & \itshape459 \\\addlinespace
                Second & A & 25 & 18 & 14 & 11 & 10 & 18 & 13 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 14 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
                & B & 55 & 59 & 63 & 64 & 64 & 65 & 68 & 72 & 73 & 73 & 76 & 81 & 83 & 84 & 85 \\
                & C & 20 & 23 & 23 & 26 & 26 & 17 & 19 & 19 & 19 & 20 & 9 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 11 \\
                & N & \itshape7801 & \itshape6363 & \itshape4018 & \itshape3166 & \itshape2643 & \itshape6279 & \itshape6151 & \itshape5336 & \itshape5208 & \itshape4861 & \itshape1707 & \itshape2268 & \itshape2615 & \itshape2905 & \itshape3053 \\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                & & \multicolumn{15}{c}{\textbf{Panel C: Third Panel}} \\\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-12}\cmidrule(l){13-17}
                First & A & 47 & 34 & 21 & 21 & 18 & 40 & 31 & 25 & 19 & 18 & 26 & 24 & 19 & 14 & 12 \\
                & B & 29 & 38 & 49 & 50 & 52 & 43 & 48 & 51 & 55 & 56 & 63 & 61 & 64 & 68 & 67 \\
                & C & 24 & 28 & 30 & 30 & 30 & 17 & 21 & 24 & 26 & 26 & 10 & 15 & 17 & 18 & 21 \\
                & N & \itshape11494 & \itshape4089 & \itshape3239 & \itshape1904 & \itshape1322 & \itshape4801 & \itshape2471 & \itshape1795 & \itshape1438 & \itshape1187 & \itshape808 & \itshape651 & \itshape557 & \itshape529 & \itshape459 \\\addlinespace
                Second & A & 25 & 18 & 14 & 11 & 10 & 18 & 13 & 9 & 8 & 8 & 14 & 8 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
                & B & 55 & 59 & 63 & 64 & 64 & 65 & 68 & 72 & 73 & 73 & 76 & 81 & 83 & 84 & 85 \\
                & C & 20 & 23 & 23 & 26 & 26 & 17 & 19 & 19 & 19 & 20 & 9 & 11 & 11 & 12 & 11 \\
                & N & \itshape7801 & \itshape6363 & \itshape4018 & \itshape3166 & \itshape2643 & \itshape6279 & \itshape6151 & \itshape5336 & \itshape5208 & \itshape4861 & \itshape1707 & \itshape2268 & \itshape2615 & \itshape2905 & \itshape3053 \\ 
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]